# Mover un elemento con css

Tags: html, css, css3

He movido un elemento con `position: relative` (y las demás variantes); pero cuando muevo el elemento parece que solo se mueve el texto y no el elemento en sí, por lo que cuando quiero adaptar un div como background con `max-width: fit-content`, se adapta al texto en su posición inicial y el texto que moví se queda afuera del div.

alguien sabrá cómo mover todo el elemento? o alguna solución?

Código HTML:

```
        <div style="
          background-color:#118a37;
          max-width: fit-content;
          ">
          <div style="
            padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            ">
            <a href="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27313b3e37318a0c247b550bccd" 
            style="
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            ">
              <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27313b3e37318a0c247b550bccd" 
              height="100" 
              width="100">
            </a>
            <span style="
            position: relative;
              bottom: 80px;
              left: 115px;
              font-size: 30px;
            ">
              <a style="
                  font-size: 30px;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  max-width: fit-content;
                  "
                  href="https://open.spotify.com/track/34gCuhDGsG4bRPIf9bb02f"
              >Thinking out Loud
                </a>
            </span>
            <div class="data" style="
            position: relative;
              left: 115px;
              bottom: 80px;
            ">
              <span>Ed Sheeran</span>
              <span>2014</span>
              <span>4:41</span> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image: imagen por si acaso]

El código es de Electron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien la pregunta, lo que se necesita es ajustar el  contenido padre, al contenido hijo.

Si el texto es más largo, o si se agrega algo más de contenido, entonces el div padre crece. Esto es lo que entendí.

Para esto cree mi propio `.card` (div padre) adaptando a la pregunta, usando algunos de tus códigos *HTML* y *CSS*.

**Cree un contenido padre.**
Display Flex es para colocar el contenido hijo uno al lado del otro.

**Importante**: el `width: fit-content` solamente se le da al contenido padre: en este caso `.card`.

```
.card {
 display: flex;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color:#118a37;
 width: fit-content;
}
```

```
<div class="card">

</div>
```

**Luego cree dos contenido hijos** para que `.left` este a la derecha y `.right` a la izquierda.
En el hijo `.left` estara un enlace que contiene una imágen.
En el hijo `.right` estarán todos los contenido: título, enlaces, span, etc.

```
.left {
 display: inline-flex;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.right {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: center; 
 width: auto;
}
```

```
<!-- contenido padre -->
<div class="card">
 
 <!-- contenido a la derecha -->
 <div class="left">
  
 </div>
 
 <!-- contenido a la izquierda -->
 <div class="right">
 
 </div>

</div>
```

Aquí si no se usa `flex`, es difil responder a la pregunta. Pero se puede.
Sin embargo,usando `flex` es mucho más fácil.

Es más legible y original crear dos archivos aparte: el HTML y la hoja de estilos CSS por separados (actualmente el código de la pregunta es un desastre).

**Un ejemplo completo.** Espero esta opción te sirva para tu trabajo. Y usa siempre está forma: *HTML* y *CSS* por separado.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0
}

.card {
 display: flex;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color:#118a37;
 width: fit-content;
}


.left {
 display: inline-flex;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.left img {
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

.right {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: center; 
 width: auto;
}

.right a {
 display: block;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 100%;
}

.data {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">

<div class="left">
 <a href="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27313b3e37318a0c247b550bccd">
  <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27313b3e37318a0c247b550bccd">
 </a>
</div> 

<div class="right">
 <a href="https://open.spotify.com/track/34gCuhDGsG4bRPIf9bb02f">Thinking out Loud</a>


<div class="data">
 <span>Ed Sheeran</span>
 <span>2014</span>
 <span>4:41</span> 
 </div>
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
```